# What does new ActionListener() mean?

Tags: java

At line number 3 what does `ActionListener()` mean after `new` keyword? I know this is structure of anonymous class but I'm not getting it.

```
Button okButton = new Button("Open a Frame");

okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        statusLabel.setText("A Frame shown to the user.");
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html

Comment: What exactly are you "not getting"?

Answer (score 5):

The `new ActionListener()` creates an anonymous inner class of the type `ActionListener`. As that ActionListener is propably not a class, but an interface, you can not simply create a new instance like `Object obj = new Object();` and done. You have to implement the methods, defined by that interface.
In your case, it is only one method `actionPerformed`.

---

**EDIT :**

Let's assume that `ActionListener` is an Interface (`public interface ActionListener`) and not an object (`public class ActionListener`), as this is the most common thing with UI development.

If you have the following code:

```
okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        statusLabel.setText("A Frame shown to the user.");
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

You already have combined a lot of statements, which causes some kind of obfuscation for young and inexperienced developers.
Let's split the statements a little bit up, to deobfuscate it a little bit

```
ActionListener myListener = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        statusLabel.setText("A Frame shown to the user.");
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
};

okButton.addActionListener(myListener);
```

Now we see in the first line a simple object instanciation, as we know it already from other objects. But, why do we need the opening brackets and why do we need to implement a method?

It is because of our assumption of ActionListener to be an interface. All methods defined within an interface are abstract and need to be implemented, before they can be used in any mean. (As side thought, if ActionListener is a `class`, the method `actionPerformed` would be defined as `abstract` within the class)

So you basically instantiate an interface. But wait, since when you can instantiate an interface?
Since you use it as anonymous!

The instantiation can be written as followed as **abstract** code:

```
ActionListener myListener = new Object implements ActionListener;
```

The construction of `Object implements ActionListener` does result in a new type, without a name, that's why anonymous. And as it has no name, you can not create another instance of it anywhere else.

---

If you split the whole code up and "extract" the anonymous parts to not be anonymous anymore, you would end up in something like this:

```
//Class MyListener
public class MyListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        statusLabel.setText("A Frame shown to the user.");
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

//Class FooBar
MyListener myListener = new MyListener();
okButton.addActionListener(myListener);
```

Comment: could plz elaborate this part of your answer better?"As that ActionListener is propably not a class, but an interface, you can not simply create a new instance like `Object obj = new Object();` and done."

Comment: I updated my post. Hope it's not too confusing, I'm running low on caffeine.

Comment: great answer... thanks a lot...



i got it from following line...



ActionListener myListener = new Object implements ActionListener;




we have anonymous class so we know its don't have name so its look like... 


ActionListener myListener = new _______ implements ActionListener;

but as there is no class name so implement keyword should not be there 

right????

Comment: The line with the `new Object implements ActionListener` is not Java but just an abstract code to point out, what is happening in the background. In Java you would just "instanciate the interface" with `new ActionListener`

Comment: Why do we call it *inner*? Why not just anonymous class?

Answer (score 2):

You are creating anonymous `ActionListener` class and implementing `actionPerformed` method.

Answer (score 2):

This syntax:

```
new ActionListener() { ... }
```

defines an anonymous class that implements the ActionListener interface. You are not creating an instance of ActionListener; you are creating an instance of this anonymous class. (The compiler actually assigns it a name—usually something like `MyEnclosingClass$1`. There will be a separate `.class` file for this anonymous class.) You can read more about anonymous inner classes in the Java tutorial.

You can use this new object immediately in a function call (as with your first code snippet) or you can assign it to a variable that has a type that is assignment-compatible with ActionListener.

```
ActionListener al = new ActionListener() { ... };
```